# How can I enable core dumps in initrd (dracut/Fedora based)?

Tags: linux, debug, dracut, qubes-os

I have a situation where a system that is intended to continue installation dumps core in initrd, effectively being unable to mount the root filesystem as a consequence.

As it tuned out, `mdadm` or `lvm` get a segmentation fault, and I was asked to provide a core dump.
Unfortunately core dumps are not enabled in initrd.

So I wonder:
Is there either kernel boot command-line parameter to enable core dumps, or is it possible to modify the initrd to enable core dumps?

The system being used is based on Fedora (actually it's Qubes OS 4.1.0).
More details on the issue could be found at https://github.com/QubesOS/qubes-issues/issues/7335#issuecomment-1080682064

Comment: In initrd, likely there is nowhere to write a core dump, and the working directory is going to be read only.

Comment: Isn't there a RAM disk?

Comment: Yes, and during initrd it usually contains a read only squashfs image.

Comment: Could I attach some USB stick to mount and receive the core dumps?

Comment: If you can get into an emergency shell while in initrd, there's a lot of things you could do.

Comment: OK, it seems there is no easy solution for the problem.