# Fedora 36 hangs on kernel 5.19.16-200.fc36

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, freeze, kernel

My desktop computer hangs after installing kernel 5.19.16. Booting into 5.19.15 works fine.

It freezes when I get to enter the password to unlock the encrypted hard drive (LUKS), which is the first thing that happens after selecting the kernel in GRUB.

I have no log in `/var/log/boot*`, because we never get to where machine can write to this file (encrypted).

The machine specs:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 7950x
MB: ASUS ROG Strix x670E-E
GPU: Rtx 4090 (Gigabytes)

The same kernel boots fine on my frame.work laptop (intel core i7 11th gen)

**UPDATE:** I have the same problem with Fedora 37 live, booting from usb: it starts correctly when monitor is connected to the integrated AMD graphics, but not when connected to Nvidia.

Comment: You can enable /etc/systemd/journald.conf to include persistent boot log, then boot into 5.9.15, then after that turn off and move into old kernel, to check what is causing the kernel freeze. See https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/store-linux-system-journals

Comment: Thank you @BenyaminLimanto. I read the link you shared. But wonder: `/var/log/journal` will still be locked (because of encryption) when startup hangs. Only `/boot` is not encrypted.

Comment: ouch... @Alireza I never remember that encryption will cause that, uhm, how about enabling kernel dump? https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_use_kdump_to_debug_kernel_crashes and https://superuser.com/questions/1713393/how-can-i-enable-core-dumps-in-initrd-dracut-fedora-based, as far as We can see the dracut shell, welp, anything should possible to be checked, as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

I updated today and my computer only stays on the start up screen of ASUS after choosing 5.19.16.201 in the boot menu.
Choosing 5.19.15.201 instead works like before.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same thing happen to me on 5.19.16.201 and then on 6.05 too when I updated yesterday. I smelt a rat here and did some digging and found this to be the solution!

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2#Reinstalling_GRUB

In my case at least, the grub config seems to have been broken somehow and these steps fixed it instantly. This can be caused by editing the wrong config files for grub / overwriting the right ones etc.

This thread illustrates the mistakes one might make to get to such behaviour.

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/f36-boot-stick-at-loading-linux-version-after-every-kernel-update/26383

(In a nutshell, remove the config files mentioned in the first link and reinstall all grub-related packages.)

P.S: Make sure GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=false is set in your grub config or else the grub menu entries/text acts weird / disappears.

Comment: Throwing this comment for the masses, but a grub reinstall did not fix the issue for me. The troubleshooting & solution hunting continues

Comment: I posted the solution that resolved my problem as a full answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to resolve this differently than other proposed answers which did not work for me.

In my case, the culprit was [Linux Firmware Minimization](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Linux_Firmware_Minimization) which removed the collective gpu firmware but never installed `amd-gpu-firmware`. [This bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2125536) claims they backported a fix to FC35 and FC36, but that obviously didn't work for me.

Following commands resolved the issue and I was able to boot into latest kernel with no issues:

```
$ sudo dnf install amd-gpu-firmware
$ sudo dnf reinstall kernel*
```

Note: I have an AMD gpu so I installed the amd gpu firmware, but OP might be able to resolve the issue they're having by explicitly installing `nvidia-gpu-firmware` & a kernel reinstall.

Thanks to Kai from [comment 18](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2125536#c18) on above-linked bug report for giving me the necessary info to fix my install.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the links. For me, both firmwares (amd and nvidia) are already installed.